# iOS Bluetooth Low Energy Speed in Background Mode

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I have an application in iOS that uses CoreBluetooth to communicate with BLE device. I've enable the `Background Modes` capability and in there the `Uses Bluetooth LE accessories`

I've notice that when the app is moved to the background the speed of the data transfer slow by about 10X.

Is there any documentation about this and what causing it?